# How to refresh the location in the browser?

Tags: python-3.x, api, python-requests, folium, python-webbrowser

The following code shows me the marked location given from the ISS API, but it always opens in a new tab.

```py
import folium
import requests
import webbrowser
import time

# Function to obtain ISS coordinates
def get_iss_position():
    url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    return data['iss_position']['latitude'], data['iss_position']['longitude']


# Create a map using the coordinates provided by the ISS API
m = folium.Map(location=get_iss_position(), zoom_start=4)

# Add a marker to the current location of ISS
marker = folium.Marker(get_iss_position())
marker.add_to(m)

# Update every 5 seconds
while True:
    print("getting ISS position")
    lat, lon = get_iss_position()
    print("Marking position")
    marker.location = [lat, lon]
    m.save('iss_map.html')
    webbrowser.open('iss_map.html', new=2)
    print("Waiting 5 seconds")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Restarting process")
```

I would like to automatically refresh the tab every 5 seconds.